# How to properly bind a DB record ID to a GridView Row (ASP GridView)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Context is an oldish ASP 2.0 application.

I have a gridView that globally works fine:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="DS" AllowPaging="true">
    ...
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyFieldName" >                    
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_ID" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="CB_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="true"  />
        </ItemTemplate>   
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_ID" runat="server"    OnCheckedChanged="CB_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="true"  />
        </EditItemTemplate>                   
    </asp:TemplateField>
    ...
</GridView>

protected void CB_radio_obligatoire_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    CheckBox checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
}
```

So all GridView's rows represent DB items.
My CB_radio_obligatoire_CheckedChanged method will need to call a storedProcedure and needs the DB record Id.

How can I set and access a this record Id into this Gridview?

I suppose the easiest way would be to set a hiddenfield bound to the ID.
If so, where should this hiddenfield be located? as a hidden column of the GridView? inside the asp:TemplateField? Inside the ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `DataKeyNames` value for a `GridViewRow` if you know the row index.

```
protected void CB_ID_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to the checkbox
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

    //cast the namingcontainer of the checkbox back to a gridviewrow
    GridViewRow row = cb.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    //as one-liner
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer;

    //get the datakeyname value from the correct row in the gridview
    int id = (int)GV.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Id"];    
}
```

Comment: Thx a ton VDWWD.
You helped me twice in 2 days :) Much appreciated!